# How can I schedule to backup my database monthly

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, backup

I want to do backup for my website database monthly without involving me everytime
I put this code everytime to backup my website `heroku pg:backups:capture --app appname`
Is there any code that i can add to backup monthly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask about monthly backups. In case you're okay with more frequent backups, you can [schedule daily backups using `heroku pg:backups:schedule`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#scheduled-backups) (`'` quotes converted to `"` for compatibility with Windows):

> ### Scheduled Backups
>
> In addition to manually triggered backups, you can schedule regular automatic backups. These run daily against the specified database.
>
> #### Set Up a Backup Schedule
>
> ```
> heroku pg:backups:schedule DATABASE_URL --at "02:00 America/Los_Angeles" --app example-app
> ```
>
> The `--at` option uses a 24-hour clock to indicate the hour of the day that you want the backup taken. It also accepts a timezone in either the full TZ format (America/Los_Angeles) or the abbreviation (PST), but we recommend using the [full TZ format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Note that [backup retention depends on the database tier](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#scheduled-backups-retention-limits), varying from 7 daily backups and 1 weekly backup all the way up to 7 daily backups, 8 weekly backups, and 12 monthly backups. If you need longer retention, you'll have to [retrieve your backups from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#downloading-your-backups) and store them elsewhere.

If you really want monthly backups and not daily ones, you'll have to schedule backups some other way, e.g. using a cron job on another system.